Fixed Tab in Search on Entities Detail Pages
Does anyone have any information about the "Fixed" tab on the Search Component on an Entities Detail Page? I only know that it appears when a page is created as a Detail Page and a Search Component is configured. Additionally, I know that it helps in filtering assets based on relationships. However, there are still some features I am unclear about. If anyone has any documentation links or blog posts that explain this in more detail, it would be very helpful.

Fixed filter helps in filtering the entities based on the id of the entity of the current page you are visiting.
Lets understand this with one of the relations under which each Asset can be linked to many Asset Detail entities using the AssetToAssetDetail relation i.e. Asset is parent to many Asset Detail entities. Using the below configuration on the search component on the Asset page, all the Asset Detail entities are fetched that have current Asset Id as the parent in the AssetToAssetDetail relation.
Rest API Search Query:
Parent('AssetToAssetDetail').id=={{Asset Id}}

System Filter Configuration

Fixed Filter Configuration

Using the combination of System and Fixed filters on the above configuration in the Asset page, all the Asset Detail entities are displayed on the page under which current asset is the parent inside AssetToAssetDetail relation.
Note: System queries will be excuted on the backend whereas Fixed queries will be executed on the frontend using the ID of the current entity being accessed.
Hope this helps!!!
